# I can sample 10% data at an intersection every day for 10 days. What should I use as n in calculating the Standard Error?

Tags: sampling, standard-error

I am able to obtain 10% of vehicle travel time information at an intersection for 10 days at the same hour of the day. If we consider that the number of vehicles arriving at the intersection in all 10 days and at the considered hour is exactly 600 vehicle per hour in all 10 days, in calculating the standard deviation of the sampling distribution of the mean, given that we have the standard deviation of the population, should I be using 10% x 10 x 600 as the n or 10% x 600?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What, exactly, do you consider your "population" to be? If the purpose of this study includes making any inferences about traffic at any other locations or at any other dates, then you certainly don't know the population parameters! And if you do know the population parameters, such as its standard deviation, then what's the point of sampling?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The standard deviation of the population has been previously modeled. My purpose is to investigate the effects of non-complete information known as market penetration rate on the results. For example I want to investigate that if we can measure 10% of the travel times how can that affect the average values.

Comment: You have not answer @whuber' s question about what the population is..  You appear to have measurements on exactly 600 vehicles, correct? If not, what is the number.  What is known about the number of vehicles per hour at other hours?

Comment: The number of vehicles in the other hours of the day are not of concern in my case. I am concentrating on one hour of the day, which has 600 vehicles passing through, in that hour in each of the 10 days. The population I am talking about is the population of vehicles in that specific hour. I should also mention that 600 vehicles pass the intersection but due to randomness in arrival the travel time values aren't going to be the same even if we had complete information for each day.

Comment: You say that the standard deviation for the process has been previously modeled. For what period? Exactly for this problem? Does it separately model between-hour and between-day components? I think you need these to estimate a proper standard error for this design.